# Java multithreading, MemoryManagerImpl issue

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, singleton

I am using multithreading within fixed threadpool Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5), the threads are calling a write method inside a Singleton class Writer:

```
public void write(String record) throws IOException {
  // some code here
  synchronized (this) {
    ioWriter.write(batch);
  }
  // some code here
}
```

I am using lazy initialization for the singleton.
Each time the write is called, I have a WARN message:

```
[WARN ] 2017-03-21 13:10:36.665 [pool-2-thread-1] MemoryManagerImpl - Owner thread expected Thread[pool-2-thread-8,5,main], got Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main]
```

I couldn't figure out the root cause of the issue, can someone help me?

Comment: A quick google search shows https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13163 which suggests that it is checking that the accessing thread should be the creator thread for some reason.

Comment: good point, I am using orc, thanks this is helpful.

Comment: A better solution would be to write to a thread-safe `Queue` and use one thread to write from the end of the queue..

Comment: I was using a blockingqueue initially, but there is a need to control which message is written when stopping (to commit its offset), so I ended up using an ArrayBlockingQueue(1), then I changed it to use Singleton.

Comment: Anyone know why it gives this warning? Everything appears to work just fine calling it from another thread. I have the right checks to ensure I can't get 2 threads calling the method at the same time.